# What is the difference between JsonReader and JsonParse in java

Tags: java, json

I have seen that both of them is used to red key value pair of a json file. For example:

The use of JsonParser to read key value of JSON file:

```
try {
    // read the json file
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

    // get a String from the JSON object
    String firstName = (String) jsonObject.get("firstname");
    System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName);

    // get a number from the JSON object
    long id =  (long) jsonObject.get("id");
    System.out.println("The id is: " + id);

    // get an array from the JSON object
    JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("languages");

    // take the elements of the json array
    for(int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("The " + i + " element of the array: "+lang.get(i));
    }

    Iterator i = lang.iterator();

    // take each value from the json array separately   
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
        System.out.println("language "+ innerObj.get("lang") +
            " with level " + innerObj.get("knowledge"));
    }

    // handle a structure into the json object
    JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("job");
    System.out.println("Into job structure, name: " + structure.get("name"));
}
```

And the use of JsonReader to read key and value of JSON file:

```
try
{
    InputStream isr=new FileInputStream("
        C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WaterNetwork
        \\web\\kusha.json"); 
    JsonReader jsr=Json.createReader(isr);
    JsonObject job=jsr.readObject();
    jsr.close();
    isr.close();
    System.out.println("Name is: "+job.getString("name"));
}
```

I searched on net but not get any useful answers till now. So I want a full explanation on working and difference between JsonReader and JsonParser in java.

Comment: I assume, as the names say, the reader lets you read line by line in a loop and the parser just parses the whole JSON object to a Java array or object or something

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, JsonReader is used to identify and read a JSON object present as a string or stream and then convert it to a proper JSON object before returning it.

You cannot *parse* the JSON object, that is, the values and arrays under an object cannot be read using getters to extract value from JSON object which, say you might get from a JSONReader object.

**But this is all abstract as we are talking about interfaces here.**
Look at the functions available in both of them to gain some clarity.